# Overlap two images and give movement and the result record it in an animated gif

Tags: graphics, programming, image-processing, image, gif-format

I need to put the circular image 1 in the image with the hole 2 (and cover the gap) the idea is to create an animated gif that shows the image 1 turning to the right and image 2 to the left in a size that can be projected (regular movement). It will be possible to do with mathematica.
Beforehand thank you very much.

EDIT

> **Something like this, but with 2 images, one turns to one side in the center and the other rotates in the opposite direction**

[How to rotate a complete graph without image rescaling while rotating](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83280/how-to-rotate-a-complete-graph-without-image-rescaling-while-rotating)

image 1

[image]

image 2
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Using the two images

```
{i1, i2}  = {Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmG0o.png"], 
  Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOkO8.png"]}
```

[image] [image]

create two polygons `Texture`d with the two images:

```
{g1, g2} = {Texture@#, Polygon[p = Table[#2 {Sin @ t, Cos @ t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}],
 VertexTextureCoordinates -> Transpose[Rescale /@ Transpose@p]]}&@@@{{i1, 1}, {i2, 1.5}};
```

and use `GeometricTransformation` + `RotationTransform` to rotate the two polygons in opposite directions controlling the rotation angle with

```
Clock[{a, b, c}, d, e]
```

whose value cycles from `a` to `b`  in steps of `c` once every  `d` seconds and stops after `e` cycles. Wrapping all with `Dynamic`

```
Dynamic @ With[{t = Clock[{0, 2 Pi, Pi/32}, 3, 1]}, 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[#2 t]] & @@@ {{g2, -1}, {g1, 1}}]]
```

gives the animation at the top.

Alternatively, you can generate a table of `frames` and `ListAnimate` them or `Export` them as a `GIF` file:

```
frames = Table[Graphics[GeometricTransformation[#, 
       RotationTransform[#2 t]] & @@@ {{g2, -1}, {g1, 1}}], {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi /64}];
ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image]

```
Export["file1.gif", frames]
```

Comment: ,thank you very much, you would be so kind to explain to me a bit the code, and how to pass the animation to an animated gif. It's just what I was using.

Comment: is there any way for the movement to be more fluid

Comment: @Walter, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am perfect